# Mailchimp list and groups - best practice?

Tags: e-commerce, mailchimp, newsletter, segment

The NGO where I work - The Danish Cyclists' Federation - we are using Mailchimp for our different newsletters. We were suggested to merge our lists to one Master List, however I'm not sure this is the way to go for us, as we have many very different newsletters, campaigns and also a webshop, and I'm not sure what is the right way to do it. Basically we have:

1) our regular newsletter called CYKLISTER (CYCLISTS), which contains news about cycling, what we do and the most popular articles are the guides and 'how to' about cycling, cycling trips, equipment and other consumer-stuff.

2) Besides that we have a campaign called 'Bike to Work', where around 60.000 people participate every year in the month of May (and join the newsletter).

3) A campaign for children biking to school - the newsletter goes to the teachers who join the campaign on behalf of their class(es).

4) We have a webshop (1905.dk), which also have their own newsletter.

5) Lastly we are about to launch a new newsletter targeted people who are interested in kids and biking: learn you kid how to ride a bike, how to pick the right bicycle, how to choose the right helmet, suggestions on trips to do on bike, offers from our webshop on childrens bikes and equipment etc.

Each of these newsletters now has their own lists, but we would like to tie  our different activities closer to 'the mother ship' - The Danish Cyclicts' Federation'. Is there a downside in combining all your lists in one master list? Are our target groups too different? And is there any troubles in having both a regular newsletter and e-commerce in the same list?

Let me know if you have any experience or good advice on this. Thanks! :)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! While I (personally) understand your question, the question itself has not so much in common with programming questions. E.g. if you had a problem in code, or in designing certain parts of your newsletter sending architecture - that would be suitable for SO.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Kia and this sounds like the best way to go to manage a large list and if you want to integrate down the road will be tons easier to do to another system.

REQUIREMENTS:

Use one list called CYKLISTER (CYCLISTS), which contains news about cycling, what we do and the most popular articles are the guides and 'how to' about cycling, cycling trips, equipment, and other consumer-stuff.

SOLUTION:

Groups to create and place under your Group Title in Mailchimp or several Group Titles if you want to break up the list by type of subscribers are:

Group = Bike to Work

Group = A campaign for children biking to school - the newsletter goes to the teachers who join the campaign on behalf of their class(es).

Group = We have a webshop (1905.dk), which also have their own newsletter.

Group = Lastly we are about to launch a new newsletter targeted people who are interested in kids and biking: learn your kid how to ride a bike, how to pick the right bicycle, how to choose the right helmet, suggestions on trips to do on bike, offers from our webshop on children's bikes and equipment etc.

To segment, even further, in your main list and among the groups you could use a "TAG" in Mailchimp which designates where they came from so like your store or just signup.

This was you could run automation on the List using numerous methods to send personalized email journeys for your subscriber base.

Hope that helps.